# passing custom object in retrofit2

Tags: java, php, android, gson, retrofit2

i am trying to pass a custom object via retrofit2, and my question is that does the server writes my custom object to json automatically or do i have to write a php file for that. In the meanwhile I am posting successfully to the server but unable to write to json.

My aim is to write custom object to server, and write the contents of custom objects to json file.

Here is my Retrofit Api

```
public interface ApsaraCatalogAPI {

    @GET("/apsaratrendz/data/apsara_json_document_v2.json")
    Call<List<ApsaraCatalogModel>> getFeed();

    @POST("/apsaratrendz/data/apsara_json_orders_document.json")
    Call<Void> setOrder(@Body OrderModel orderModel);
}
```

Here is my calling api function

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int total = 0;
        if(v.getId()==R.id.fabButtonCart && cartlist.size()!=0)
        {
            // get details from shared preferences
            OrderModel orderModel = new OrderModel();
            orderModel.setDate(getDate());
            orderModel.setName("ssdfs");
            orderModel.setEmail("sdf@gmail.com");
            orderModel.setNoofitems(String.valueOf(cartlist.size()));
            orderModel.setOrderno("32335");
            orderModel.setPhone("9896566444");
            for(int i=0; i<cartlist.size();i++){
                Productdetail pd = new Productdetail();
                pd.getSellingprice(String.valueOf(cartlist.get(i).getSellingPrice()));
                pd.getPid(cartlist.get(i).getEANCode());
                total += cartlist.get(i).getSellingPrice();
                orderModel.getProductdetails().add(pd);
            }
            //
            // now go for insertion using retrofit
            requestData(orderModel);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total Price : Rs."+total+"/-", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cart is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

And here is my service request for retrofit api, I am passing the newly created POJO OrderModel class.

```
private void requestData(OrderModel orderModel) {

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(ENDPOINT)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        ApsaraCatalogAPI service = retrofit.create(ApsaraCatalogAPI.class);
        Call<Void> call = service.setOrder(orderModel);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Log.d("InApi","Yipppie");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("InApi","Kaboom");
        }
    });

    }
```

My POJO Class is given below:

```
import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.List;
public class OrderModel {

    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phone;
    private String orderno;
    private String date;
    private String noofitems;
    private List<Productdetail> productdetails = new ArrayList<Productdetail>();
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param name
     * The name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The email
     */
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param email
     * The email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The phone
     */
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param phone
     * The phone
     */
    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The orderno
     */
    public String getOrderno() {
        return orderno;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param orderno
     * The orderno
     */
    public void setOrderno(String orderno) {
        this.orderno = orderno;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The date
     */
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param date
     * The date
     */
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The noofitems
     */
    public String getNoofitems() {
        return noofitems;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param noofitems
     * The noofitems
     */
    public void setNoofitems(String noofitems) {
        this.noofitems = noofitems;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The productdetails
     */
    public List<Productdetail> getProductdetails() {
        return productdetails;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param productdetails
     * The productdetails
     */
    public void setProductdetails(List<Productdetail> productdetails) {
        this.productdetails = productdetails;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

productdetails class :

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Productdetail {

    private String pid;
    private String sellingprice;
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The pid
     * @param s
     */
    public String getPid(String s) {
        return pid;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param pid
     * The pid
     */
    public void setPid(String pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The sellingprice
     * @param s
     */
    public String getSellingprice(String s) {
        return sellingprice;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param sellingprice
     * The sellingprice
     */
    public void setSellingprice(String sellingprice) {
        this.sellingprice = sellingprice;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the JSON response of the server? Based on the error message your API returns a list of objects, but you specified a single object.

Comment: I dont want my api to return anything(updated question), just want to write my pojo to json, so do i require php file to do that or does the server handles this, ?. I am very new to retrofit and php..

Comment: Everything looks good now from the Retrofit side.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit generates the json based on your POJO and set it on the post payload.
So, in this case:

```
@POST("/apsaratrendz/data/apsara_json_orders_document.json")
Call<Void> setOrder(@Body OrderModel orderModel);
```

the body of the post will be a json representation of orderModel.

If you need to change the names of the atributtes generated in the json you can use SerializedName Annotation, its very useful:

```
public class OrderModel {
    @SerializedName("other_name_for_json") 
    private String name;
```

Hope it helps.