# how to send arraylist request with object of string and image in android kotlin retrofit 2?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit2, multipart

Request payload -->

```
{
name:Employee one
phone:9876543210
companyName:ows
abn:ows1234
service:4
email:souravc+1001@pitangent.com
licenses[0].license
licenses[0].expDate:2022-12-06
insurences[0].insurence
insurences[0].expDate:2022-12-06
type:INVITE
locations[]:1
}
```

licenses[0].license ----> this is file type
licenses[0].expDate:2022-12-06 ------> this is string type

We using retrofit library and my apiService class

```
@Multipart
@PUT("employees/{id}")
suspend fun putEmployeeUpdate(
@Path("id") id: Int,
@Part("name") name: String,
@Part("phone") phone: String,
@Part("companyName") companyName: String,
@Part("abn") abn: String,
@Part("service") service: Int,
@Part("email") email: String,
@Part("locations[]") locations: ArrayList<Int>,
@Part insurences: Array<MultipartBody.Part?>,
@Part licenses: Array<MultipartBody.Part?>,
): JsonObject
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36544082

Answer (score 0):

Define your End-Point like, hopefully it will work.

```
@POST("your_end_point")
Call<Void> yourRequest(@Body CustomModel model)
```

Comment: payload request as an image, so it has to be send in multipart